# How to improve performance of a folder with many files in windows server 2008 sp2?

Tags: windows, ntfs, windows-server-2008

On a windows server 2008sp2 box, I have a folder with more than 180,000 files(images). Since this folder is used to store images for a legacy application, I cannot change the directory structure. Is there any way to increase the performance (access time/search) of this folder?

Comment: How many gigs approx of data?

Answer (score 1):

If money is no object, then build a RAID of SSDs.  Most SSDs can provide 500 MB/s read and 400 MB/s (@ 512 GB capacity).  In a RAID 6 of, say, eight 512 GB SSDs, a read performance over 1 GB/s is easily obtainable.  (8 × 500 MB/s = 4000 MB/s.)  At that rate your other hardware will probably limit you to 2 GB/s.

Comment: Very good suggestion, thank you. But, I was looking for a software solution for now. Also, these files are not accessed very frequently.

Comment: @user1507435 How much RAM do you have? Another method is allocating RAM to a variety of different kinds of caching.

Comment: 4GB. Upgrading RAM should be effective too. Thanks.